# Cannot find a module imported by another module

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have a file structure like this

```
└── myproject
    ├── src
        ├── a.py
        ├── b.py
```

module a contains `a` class that is imported in by module `b` like this:

```
from src.a import some_class
```

when I try to import `b` from another class:

```
from myproject.src import b
```

I get this error:

```
from src.a import some_class

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

why can't python find package src? how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this import in `b.py`

```py
from .a import some_class
```